# How to compute the ground state energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, bose-einstein-condensate

I am trying to compute the ground state energy of the following hamiliton.
The system is originally a weakly interacting bose system and I get the following hamiltonian after bogoliubov transformation
$
H_{\mathrm{MF}}=-\mu N_{0}+\frac{N_{0}^{2} u}{2 V}-\sum_{p>0}\left(\epsilon_{p}-\mu+2 u n_{0}-E_{p}\right)+\sum_{p>0} E_{p}\left(\alpha_{p}^{\dagger} \alpha_{p}+\alpha_{-p}^{\dagger} \alpha_{-p}\right)$

$\alpha_{p}$ and $\alpha_{-p}$ come from the bogoliubov transformation

this is the hint they gave me
Hint: You may assume the infinite momentum sum converges (in fact it is, if you treat the potential  V  more carefully), and show it is  $O\left(u^{2}\right)$ .

any idea how to compute the so called ground state energy?

Answer (score 1):

Your Hamiltonian is diagonal in the quasiparticle $\alpha$ basis, and commutes with the number operator $\alpha_q^\dagger \alpha_q$. The ground state energy is the lowest energy state of the system, i.e. the smallest eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian.

Your system has a ground state if and only if all of the $E_p$'s are positive. (Otherwise, we could always lower the system's energy by creating more quasiparticles - these are bosons, so we can make as many as we want). Therefore the smallest energy eigenvalue is just the eigenstate $\alpha_p^\dagger \alpha_p \equiv 0$, i.e.

$$
E_0 =-\mu N_{0}+\frac{N_{0}^{2} u}{2 V}-\sum_{p>0}\left(\epsilon_{p}-\mu+2 u n_{0}-E_{p}\right)$$